# refreshing data in tag-it after updating tag table

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using two scripts on my mvc page, one that uses Tag-It and the other which allows me to add new tags via a dialog box. However the below script does not load the new data when a new tag is created and I am wondering how I can get it to load the new tags. When a tag is created by a user as soon as the dialog box is closed it should be available in Tag-It to tag. This is not the case and I have to reload the page in order to see the new tag in Tag-It.

Dialog Box for creating new Tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialog = $('#dialog');
    var tags = $('#singleFieldTags');
    var url = '@Url.Action("CreateTag")';
    $('#addtag').click(function () {
        dialog.show();
    });
    $('#createtag').click(function () {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.post(url, form.serialize(), function (data) {
            if (data) {
                //method for reloading tag it data....
                form.get(0).reset(); 
                dialog.hide(); 
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Tag-It script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var sampleTags = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AllTags)');
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the new `Tag` has been successfully saved, you can add its name property to the existing tag list using `$(element).tagit("createTag", "tagName");` [Refer documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)

```
 $('#createtag').click(function () {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function (data) {
      if (data) {
        //method for reloading tag it data....
        form.get(0).reset(); 
        dialog.hide(); 
        // Add the new tag
        var tagName = ? // based on a previous related question, this would be data.Name
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit("createTag", tagName);
      }
  });
})
```

Comment: I cant remember which was the question we discussed this script for creating a new tag - but I think it returned json with 2 properties (`Id` and `Name`) so I'm just guessing its `data.Name` (but test it with a dummy value - e.g. `var tagName = 'my new tag';`

Comment: I have... it works fine! data.Name is correct. Plus one and big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as

```
$('#singleFieldTags').tagit('add', data);
```

This is assuming `data` contains only new tags. Otherwise make sure to retrieve tag from `data`.

Comment: plus one for answering however Stephens post was a little clearer as he has helped before.